# boot-clj: browser repl after cider-jack-in

Tags: emacs, clojure, clojurescript, cider, boot-clj

My workflow for starting a "boot dev" process within emacs for using it with cider afterwards was something like this:

- go to a shell buffer.
- enter "boot dev"
- wait until the message "Time Elapsed..."
- cider-connect (Enter, Enter)

In the case it is a ClojureScript Project, one could start a browser repl with:

```
(start-repl)
```

When using cider-jack-in to ease this a bit I get problems with the last step, the ClojureScript repl. Here's the beginning of the error message:

```
boot.user> (start-repl)
<< started Weasel server on ws://127.0.0.1:45341 >>
<< waiting for client to connect ... java.lang.NullPointerException
    at clojure.java.io$make_parents.invokeStatic(io.clj:443)
    at clojure.java.io$make_parents.doInvoke(io.clj:438)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:410)
```

(the full message can be found here: http://pastebin.com/chBNByKG)

I did add a ~/.boot/profile.boot according to the cider manual.

Answer (score 0):

Use `cider-jack-in-clojurescript` (`C-c M-J` by default) instead of `cider-jack-in` to get the ClojureScript REPL. (Or connect to an external REPL.) It doesn't work otherwise, at least with the current CIDER (0.14 at the time or writing.)

Comment: Do you get a browser repl when using cider-jack-in-clojurescript? I'm getting a rhino cljs repl...